# how to add prefix in sql to 'invoice_id' column in table sales

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to sql. So please help....

```
create table sales (
invoice_id int identity(1,1) primary key NOT NULL ,
productId int foreign key references Product(proId) NOT NULL,
qty int not null,
dateofsale date default getdate())
```

thank you

Comment: What exception you getting ?

Comment: havent got any exceptions yet. But i was hoping to append some character to invoice_id column like "inv"+invoice_id so the result will be like "inv1"

Comment: what if i change the datatype to varchar for invoice_id?
will it be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **invoice_id** column is **INT** and **identity** with **primary key**, so you can't add any prefix on that column.

If you wants to add prefix on some column it should be **varchar/nvarchar (string)** column

You can set prefix for string/varchar many ways:

- CONCAT('prefixValue', columnName)
- 'prefixValue'+columnName

Comment: then it simple just add your prefix like : 'test'+ columnValue

Answer (score 3):

Use CONCAT function or simply '+' operator like `'YourPrefix' + invoice_id`